# Change MySQL Schema at runtime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a multi-tenant application. It's a school management system. 
The application is configured to use Schema-Per-Tenant approach. But this is limited to only one schema access per request. I want to use three different schemas per request.

Each user has two schemas and an application wide common schema. Totally 3. I want to enable my app to switch between all three schemas under one rest call.
For example, if the request is to add a new Student, the student must be added to SCHEMA_A, an auto-generated user account for the student must be added to the COMMON_SCHEMA and the studentId must be added to the class in SCHEMA_B.
At present I use

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("USE SCHEMA_A").executeUpdate();
add(student);

entityManager.createNativeQuery("USE COMMON_SCHEMA").executeUpdate();
add(generateUserForStudent(student));

entityManager.createNativeQuery("USE SCHEMA_B").executeUpdate();
addStudentToClass(student);
```

**it works.**

But I wonder if it is a valid approach.

I also am not sure if it will cause conflicts when multiple users are logged in at the same time.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: This really isn’t schema per tenant. If it was, you wouldn’t need to access multiple schemes in a single call.

Comment: Your approach should work assuming you’re creating an entity manager per request. A different approach would be to split your code into multiple API requests to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: I have the EntityManager @Autowired